# show city depending on the state selected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My script is working, the problem is that I am on a page to edit, and was to appear all data

```
<tr>
    <td class="left">Estado</td>
    <td>
        <select name="estado" id="select2_1" onChange="buscar_cidades()" style="width: 40%;">
             <option value="">--</option>
             <?php foreach ($arrEstados as $value => $name) {
                   echo   "<option value='{$value}' ".selected($estado,$value).">{$name}</option>";
             }?>
        </select>
   </td>
</tr>                  
<tr>
    <td class="left">Cidade</td>
    <td>
     <div id="load_cidades">     
        <select name="cidade" id="select2_2" style="width: 50%;">
          <option value="">Select the state</option> 
        </select>
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
function buscar_cidades(){

  var estado = $('#select2_1').val();
  if(estado){
    var url = 'ajax_cidades.php?estado='+estado;
    $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
      $('#load_cidades').html(dataReturn);
    });
  }
}
```

my file ajax_cidades.php

```
<?php   
require_once('application/config/database.php');

$estado = $_GET['estado'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM loc_cidade WHERE id_uf = $estado ORDER BY nome";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
  $dados = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  $arrCidades[$dados['id']] = $dados['nome'];
}
?>


                                            <select name="cidade" id="select2_2" style="width: 50%;">
                                                <?php foreach($arrCidades as $value => $nome){
                                                    echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$nome}</option>";
                                                  }
                                                ?>
```

I already tried everything and could not, function 'selected' checks are equal to brand as 'selected'

print screen

http://oi44.tinypic.com/pu5w6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are having your ajax_cidades.php loop through the same data twice.

```
<?php   
require_once('application/config/database.php');

$estado = $_GET['estado'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM loc_cidade WHERE id_uf = $estado ORDER BY nome";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo '<select name="cidade" id="select2_2" style="width:50%;">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
  $dados = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  echo '<option value="'.$dados['id'].'">'.$dados['nome'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

also, try debugging what the ajax call is returning, by adding

```
console.log(dataReturn)
```

to your function after `$.get(url, function(dataReturn) {`

then check your console to make sure your page is returning the data expected.